# How to wrap function and extend custom arguments with right type

Tags: typescript, generic-type-argument

I want wrap callback function and extend custom arguments, And i get error type alert

```
const func = (a: string) => {
   console.log(a);
}

type Options = {
  force?: boolean
};

const wrapFunc = <A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R) => {
  const wrappedFunc = (...args: A & [options?: Options]) => {
     const options: Options = 'force' in args[args.length - 1] ? args.pop() : {};
     fn(...(args as A))
  }

  return wrappedFunc;
}

const newFunc = wrapFunc(func);

newFunc('a', {force: true})
// Argument of type '["a", { force: true; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[a: string] & // [options?: Options | undefined]'.
//  Type '["a", { force: true; }]' is not assignable to type '[a: string]'.
//    Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.(2345)
```

here is reproduced [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAhgLhtAJwEswBzASjQD4YBvAWACgYXRIQAbAUwDoORS2cgG4mAXyZMoATwAOXGAHlZUIuAho6TFnBAFgXAPx4ARiE5csYcaMZM20GAHcCWWQDEkKdAB4AgjBcAB5QXGAAJhpW0gDaALoANDAASlQYcGB4GDw5WASkEHh+lKg0ySU0DMwwDrAubvLhnsia2bn5hTABAGQwMSAqapDGSoPqcRVa1Sw16rADqup4youQmgDkuvpc6zAkMHkFMYcQfGGkUAAWMAC0MACMcTCGBx08sgMYlHi0YrYzOjAbR42A6Bw0xXI2hgEjs1QIXCgCAIYGcrlkjWawFssPscxgYC4TixmnqHi86S8IkkjEJxIp6yw6yStC2BjwUAICC4YnIQA)

Could somebody help me make is right. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnE3vw) solve your problem? If yes, I will write the answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks, it dosen't solve options optional issue.  and i wanna make wrapfunc type hint readable.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the optional options part. How about [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZZLEm)? It makes `options` optional, and I think it has better hinting. Note: you can try `[...mainArgs: A, options?: Options]`; however, you may have some errors depending on your tsconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` operator is not what you should use. `number[] & {prop: string}` will expect an array with a `prop` property typed as a `string`, not another element. To push an element to a generic array parameter, you can do as follows:
`<A extends unknown[]>(args: [...A, Options]`

This one isn't suitable for us since we want to have optional options, and it can be achieved by telling the compiler that we expect `A` or `A` with options:

```
args: [...A, Options] | A
```

Implementation:

```
const wrapFunc = <A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R) => {
  const wrappedFunc = (...args: [...A, Options] | A) => {
    const options: Options = 'force' in args[args.length - 1] ? args.pop() : {};
    fn(...(args.slice(-1) as A));
  };

  return wrappedFunc;
};

// const newFunc: (...args: [a: string] | [string, Options]) => void
const newFunc = wrapFunc(func);
```

This works as expected; however, the label of `a` is removed in the hinting when you also accept `Options`. To fix it, we should use [labeled tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) as follows:

```
const wrappedFunc = (...args: [...mainArgs: A, options: Options] | A) => {}
```

This way hinting will be better:

```
// const newFunc: (...args: [a: string] | [a: string, options: Options]) => void
const newFunc = wrapFunc(func);
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZZLEm)

Note: You can also consider using the following approach, however, it may throw some Typescript errors depending on your tsconfig:

```
const wrappedFunc = (...args: [...mainArgs: A, options?: Options]) => {}

// const newFunc: (a: string, options?: Options) => voi
const newFunc = wrapFunc(func);
```